# How to set external folders in classpath through command line while starting wildfly server

Tags: jboss, classpath, jboss7.x, wildfly, wildfly-8

I want to set external folders in classpath through command line while starting wildfly server.

Unable to set it through -p

```
standalone.sh -p path of folder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `standalone.sh -h` to see the valid options.

`-p` is not a valid option.

Besides, WildFly uses modular classloading via JBoss Modules. The classpath is almost meaningless in this context, exception for bootstrapping JBoss Modules.